# ServiceStack RedisMqServer fails in Azure

Tags: azure, servicestack, servicestack.redis

We have an instance of RedisMqServer hosted on one of our sites to process emails. When testing locally the queue performs perfectly. When deployed to Windows Azure the queue will process any messages in the in queue on start but after a few minutes will fail to handle new messages. The set up is as follows:

```
 var mqService = new RedisMqServer(container.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>());
 container.Register<IMessageService>(mqService);
 mqService.RegisterHandler<EmailMessage>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);
 mqService.Start();
```

Publishing to the queue:

```
   using (var mqClient = TryResolve<IMessageService>().MessageFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient())
        {
            mqClient.Publish(new EmailMessage
            {
                From = "support@mysite.com",
                To = request.Email,
                Subject = "Email Subject",
                Body = body
            });
        }
```

There is never any problem with the publish. The messages successfully make it into redis mq:EmailMessage.inq.

Checking the worker thread status we see:

```
Worker: mq:EmailMessage.priorityq, 
Status: Started, ThreadStatus: Background, WaitSleepJoin, 
LastMsgAt: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Worker: mq:EmailMessage.inq, 
Status: Started, 
ThreadStatus: Background, WaitSleepJoin, 
LastMsgAt: 5/22/2014 9:57:23 PM
```

Is there a problem with how this setup? Is it ok to host RedisMqServer in IIS?